# How to remove everything from string after two or more spaces in a row

Tags: jquery, regex

How can I remove everything from `$(this).text()` in the snippet below that appears after two (or more) spaces in a row, including these spaces ?

```
$(this).find('td.export').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':visible')) {
        html += '<td>' + $(this).text() + '</td>';
    }
});
```

**Example:** If `$(this).text()` = "`text1  text2`" then I would only need text1.

**Note:** I am only looking for two or more spaces in a row so if there is only one space then nothing should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
theString.replace(/ {2,}.*/gm, '');
```

Or if you want to ignore spaces at the begin of a line:

```
theString.replace(/(\S) {2,}.*/gm, '$1');
```

test case:

```
var theString =
'Hello world  there are 2 spaces\n\
another row       with more     spaces\n\
      yet another row     whith spaces at the begin of the line';

var result = theString.replace(/ {2,}.*/gm, '');
var result2 = theString.replace(/(\S) {2,}.*/gm, '$1');

alert(result);
alert(result2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! Combining this with $.trim works perfect and is all I needed here. :)

Comment: If you want to detect other whitespaces than only spaces created by the spacebar then use `\s` instead of a simple space character.
You can trim the result also without an additional function call by the following expression:
`theString.replace(/^\s*(\S.*?)(?:\s{2,}.*|$)/gm, '$1');`

Comment: The comma in `{2,}` isn't required in this special case, since the following dot is matching the space character as well. `{2,}` is semantically correct to match "two or more" of the preceding character (or subexpression). `{2}` means exact two occurrences, which could also simply be noted as two bare spaces or `\s\s`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The OP has edited the requirements. We are no longer leaving the first space+characters group and deleting the second space+characters group, we are just deleting two spaces + characters. So the task is completely different. Leaving the original because it is interesting anyway.

**Original:** Leaving the first "space + characters" block, removing everything from the first space after that block.

**Using a lambda function in the replacement**

Search: `^( \S+)[ ]{2}.*`

In the replace function, replace with Group 1.

- `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `( \S+)` matches the first space, followed by the first non-space characters and captures to Group 1
- `[ ]{2}.*` matches the second space and everything till the end of the string

Here is tested code (see [demo](http://js.do/code/39690))

```
<script>
var subject = ' text1 text2';
var regex = /^( \S+)[ ]{2}.*/;
replaced = subject.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
     return group1;
 });
document.write("<br>*** Replacements ***<br>");
document.write(replaced);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! This looks great but I'll go with the above as that's all I need here.